# why expo init failed

Tags: react-native, expo

```
expo : The term 'expo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
 expo init Weather
 ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (expo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I installed expo globally by using 'npm install expo-cli --global'. but here I can't create a project using expo int. how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only thing missing is to add the expo executable to your path.

For Windows 10, you can simply add the npm folder to your path environment variable.

1. Hit Windows key and search for Environment variables.
2. Inside the Path variable under System variables, add a new entry (entries are separated by semicolons) with this content (without /node_modules ):

OR if you are using yarn

`C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin`

Open a new command prompt and enter

> `expo`

If you are using yarn global add expo-cli, try `npm install -g expo-cli`.

If you can get some output, :) Happy, You are good to go.